# Как подключиться к MS SQL и победить проблему с TLS10?

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring

Столкнулся с проблемой подключения:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]
```

Пробовал по гайдам править файл java.security, jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms удалить TLSv1. Но параметра этого нет. И как я понял это проблема на версиях java > 11.

Как быть?